# Why are constructors not allowed to be ref-qualified?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a particular reason why constructors cannot be ref-qualified? This code will not compile:

```
class MyClass {
  public:
    MyClass() && {}
};

int main() {
    const auto obj = MyClass();
}
```

> error: constructors may not be ref-qualified

Comment: Probably because that makes no sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rvalue-`this` qualification exists to be able to differentiate between `val.func()`, `std::move(val).func()` and `Type().func()` (the first calling `&`, the latter two calling `&&`). That allows you to make it explicit that `func` can move from the contents of `*this`.

But in a constructor, you're initializing the object. It makes no sense to move from the contents of `*this`, since the object is still being initialized.

So the only possible reason for wanting to qualify a constructor would be to have a constructor differentiate between constructing a prvalue temporary and constructing a non-temporary. And such differentiation is overall pointless. And dangerous.

And with guaranteed elision, it is self defeating. Because thanks to C++17's guaranteed elision, `auto val = Typename();` doesn't produce a temporary at all. It merely initializes `val`, *exactly as if* you had done `Typename val();`. So, when exactly should the `&&` `this` constructors be called?

In the end, it's an idea that makes no sense.

Comment: When reading about ref-qualifiers, the idea of an object that can only be used in a temporary context seemed "interesting" at first. Thank you for mentioning guaranteed elision too.

Comment: I still think its interesting for exactly this reason. You could delete the non-ref qualified constructor and only allow this&& to be constructed. There are situations where you don't immediately assign the object to a variable but just keep it in temporary context like for example printf("%s", std::string_view{stringlike}.data()) although in this case it makes of course no difference.

Comment: *"It merely initializes val, exactly as if you had done `Typename val();`..."* No, the latter is a **function declaration due to vexing parse**.

Comment: @glades: If a user-defined struct/class has a member pointing to another instance of the same struct/class, it's not needed to create a separate pointer to manage it. But it can still be nice to keep track of the total number of named pointers pointing to linked tree/graph of class instances -- in order to delete all at the right time automatically. Ref-qualifiers on constructor would enable that too (without anything external).